# What is the correct way to use variable symbols in a hash?

Tags: ruby, variables, hash, key, symbols

I have two arrays:

```
people_keys   = ['id', 'name', 'email']
people_values = [[1, 'Tarzan', 'tarzan@jungle.com'],
                 [2, 'Jane',   'jane@jungle.com'  ]]
```

and I want to make an array of people:

```
people = []
people_values.each do |person_values|
  person = {}
  person_values.each_with_index do |person_value, index|
    person[people_keys[index]] = person_value
  end
  people.push( person )
end
```

This gives me the following result:

```
people # => [{"id"=>1, "name"=>"Tarzan", "email"=>"tarzan@jungle.com"},
       #     {"id"=>2, "name"=>"Jane",   "email"=>"jane@jungle.com"  }]
```

I want to make `id`, `name` and `email` symbols instead of strings,
so I came up with the following:

I replaced

```
person[people_keys[index]] = person_value
```

with

```
person[:"#{people_keys[index]}"] = person_value
```

This gives me the following result:

```
people # => [{:id=>1, :name=>"Tarzan", :email=>"tarzan@jungle.com"},
       #     {:id=>2, :name=>"Jane",   :email=>"jane@jungle.com"  }]
```

This works just fine but seems like it could be done better/cleaner,
but I am unable to find a better solution.

I'd like to know if there is in fact a better solution for this problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving working code, which makes it on-topic for [codereview.se].

Comment: @theTinMan: It's on-topic here, it's off-topic on Code Review: *" it's okay to ask 'Does this code follow common best practices?', but not 'What is the best practice regarding X?'"*. The difference is that he's asking to **how** he could improve it, not **what**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby's String class has a [`to_sym`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-to_sym) method:

> Returns the Symbol corresponding to str, creating the symbol if it did not previously exist.

Comment: ty, if I Googled on 'ruby string to symbol' I probably should have found it. For some reason I sticked with the word 'hash' in most of my searches.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
people_values.map { |person| people_keys.map(&:to_sym).zip(person).to_h }
```